# Azure Search, return non relevant results

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Here are 2 search examples,

you can see the first search for "yael0079" 
return an object where the email filed is yael0079@gmail.com as top score.

The second search for "yael0079@gmail.com" 
return the object from before somewhere far below.

Now, I know the '@' tag consider as space, but still, I would expect the same object will get the higher score.

[image: first search]

[image: second search]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case, since the @ sign is considered punctuation, your query becomes `yael0079 OR gmail.com.` The term `gmail.com` matches also in other fields of the documents returned what adds to the overall relevance score. To learn more about query processing and scoring in Azure Search, please read: [How full text search works in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there a good guid how to treat the '@' sign as part of the phrase ?